# How to remove the tags using Meta in angular 4

Tags: angular, tags, meta-tags

I am able to set the tags dynamically in index.html with [Meta](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Meta-class.html) concept in angular 4.but when I try to remove tags.its not
removing ,How can I remove the tags whatever I have added before?

here is what I tried:
setting the tags:

```
import {Meta ,MetaDefinition } from '@angular/platform-browser';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-share-video',
  templateUrl: './share-video.component.html',
  })
export class ShareVideoComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(public metaServic:Meta){}
ngOnInit(){
    const ogtitle: MetaDefinition   =  { name: 'og:title', content: 'Grace' };
    const ogSitename: MetaDefinition = { name: 'og:site_name', content: 'My Favourite Albums'};
    const ogUrl: MetaDefinition = { name: 'og:url', content: 'https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Meta-class.html'};
    const ogdesc: MetaDefinition = { name: 'og:description', content: 'angular 4 share video description'};
    this.metaService.addTag(ogtitle);
    this.metaService.addTag(ogSitename);
    this.metaService.addTag(ogUrl);
    this.metaService.addTag(ogdesc);
  }        
ngOnDestroy() {
   this.metaService.removeTag("property='og:title'");
   this.metaService.removeTag("property='og:site_name'");
   this.metaService.removeTag("property='og:url'");
   this.metaService.removeTag("property='og:description'");
    }
}
```

In the destroy method I am removing the tags, but these tags are not removing,how can I remove the tags?
followed this:[meta tags blog](https://netbasal.com/exploring-the-new-meta-service-in-angular-version-4-b5ba2403d3e6)

Comment: is your destroy called ? did u verified?

Comment: its calling destroy method

Comment: I don't see any issue in your code. try like this this.meta.addTag({ name: 'og:title', content: 'Grace' }). if still not working before removetag try to getTag and printout console log.

Comment: yes add tags are working properly,but this remove tag is not working

Comment: did you tried getTag before removeTag

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The attribute selector that you are trying to use is `name`, not `property`.

You have to use

```
this.metaService.removeTag("name='og:title'");
this.metaService.removeTag("name='og:site_name'");
this.metaService.removeTag("name='og:url'");
this.metaService.removeTag("name='og:description'");
```

instead of

```
this.metaService.removeTag("property='og:title'");
this.metaService.removeTag("property='og:site_name'");
this.metaService.removeTag("property='og:url'");
this.metaService.removeTag("property='og:description'");
```

[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/lLEwuzJ91j0vWlpRjLy0?p=preview)

Comment: But the `remove("property='og:title'");` works as well

Answer (score 1):

Angular 6+ you need to use for `this.metaService.removeTag("property='og:description'")` etc... Because of with `this.metaService.removeTag("name='og:title'");` doesn't work.

Comment: That isn't an Angular v6+ issue, it's just that some meta tags use the `name` field and some use `property`. All of the OpenGraph tags use `property` for example.

Answer (score 0):

All of the [OpenGraph tags](https://ogp.me/) should be using "property", and not "name", for both adding and removing the tags. You were adding with "name" and trying to remove with "property".

Fixed code:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    const ogtitle: MetaDefinition =  { property: 'og:title', content: 'Grace' };
    const ogSitename: MetaDefinition = { property: 'og:site_name', content: 'My Favourite Albums'};
    const ogUrl: MetaDefinition = { property: 'og:url', content: 'https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform-browser/index/Meta-class.html'};
    const ogdesc: MetaDefinition = { property: 'og:description', content: 'angular 4 share video description'};
    this.metaService.addTag(ogtitle);
    this.metaService.addTag(ogSitename);
    this.metaService.addTag(ogUrl);
    this.metaService.addTag(ogdesc);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
   this.metaService.removeTag("property='og:title'");
   this.metaService.removeTag("property='og:site_name'");
   this.metaService.removeTag("property='og:url'");
   this.metaService.removeTag("property='og:description'");
  }
```

For other page metadata like [Twitter Cards](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/markup) or normal metadata like `description`, `author`, `keywords`, etc you use "name".

- `"name='description'"`
- `"name='author'"`
- `"name='twitter:description'"`
- `"name='twitter:image'"`
- `"name='twitter:image:alt'"`
- `"name='keywords'"`